# Making a 1-bit adder in python but when i input (0,1,0) ,(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1) i either get none for the sum or none for the carry out

Tags: python-3.x

But when I input (0,1,0) ,(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1). I either get none for the sum or none for the carryout. and I'm not sure what is wrong with the code and why I'm getting this issue. I think I have made most of the truth tables correctly based on their conditions I'm just not sure why I'm getting none as a sum when it should represent 1

```
***
   def main():
        a = input("Enter 'A' value(0-1):  ")
        b = input("Enter 'B' value(0-1): ")
        c = input("Enter 'Cin' value(0-1): ")     

        def bitadder(a,b,c):
            def xor_g(a,b):
               if a != "1":
                if b == "0":
                    if a == "0" and b == "0":
                        if a or b == "0":
                            return("0")
                        else:
                            return("1")
            if a == "1":
                if b != "0":
                    if a == "1" and b == "1":
                        if a or b == "1":
                            return("0")
                        else:
                            return("1")
            if b == "1":
                if a == "0":
                    if a == "0" and b == "1":
                        if a or b == "0":
                            return("1")
                if b == "0":
                    if a == "1":
                        if a == "1" and b == "0":
                            if a or b == "1":
                                return("1")
                       
                #XOR logic gate
        xor_g(a,b)
        def and_g(a,b):
            if a == "1" and b == "1":
                return("1")
            else:
                return("0")
                #AND logic gate
        and_g(a,b)

        def or_g(a,b):
            if a == "0" or b == "0":
                return("0")
            else:
                return("1")
                #OR logic gate
            or_g(a,b)
            d = xor_g(a,b)
            sum = xor_g(d,c)
            g = and_g(d,c)
            e = and_g(a,b)
            out = xor_g(g,e)
            print(sum,out)
            bitadder(a,b,c)
 #I think I have made most of the truth tables correctly based on their conditions I'm just not sure why I'm getting none as a sum when it should represent 1
***


  main()
```